# What does the PDO::PARAM_EVT_* constants do?

Tags: php, pdo

I can't find any information on these constants but the sparse bit [the documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) gives.

What can they be used for, and do I to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you cannot use them as an end-user. Those constants are used internally on a per-driver basis for handling of the events described. Browsing the source at http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/ I did not find any end-user functionality.

Comment: I had hoped for some way of injecting callbacks for those events. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Except for the `alloc`/`free` variants, you can create your hooks to events quite easily by extending the `PDO` and/or `PDOStatement` class.